# How to forward all Options requests to backend server with Azure Api Management

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to create a single policy that will forward all Options requests to the backend server? The only way I have figured out how to do this is by creating a new Options operation for each endpoint.  That seems like a lot of unnecessary work since I want all options requests to be forwarded to the backend.

How can I create a single policy to forward all Options requests to the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is currently possible, so your only options are:

1. Create a separate OPTIONS operation in each endpoint.
2. Set up CORS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/7689d277-8abe-472a-a78c-e6d4bd43455d#CORS) policy on a product or global level, so that OPTIONS requests would be served by APIM and not forwarded to backend at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is, operation template support wildcard /*

I am trying this, but since our API requires an SubscriptionKey, it is still not working. Since ApiMgmt will return 401 for options request, since browsers dont send the SubscriptionKey header.

Would be nice with the possibility to open single operations...

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/19450117-feature-to-ignore-api-management-subscription-key